# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_objc_readClassPair", referenced from: __ARCLite__load() in libarclite_iphoneos.a(arclite.o)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, image-processing

I am integrating OpenCV framework in iOS application for sample image processing app. But I am getting following error :

```
enter Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_objc_readClassPair", referenced from:
  __ARCLite__load() in libarclite_iphoneos.a(arclite.o)
```

I am using Xcode7.0 and base SDK 8.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying turning off "Implicitly Link Objective-C Runtime Support" in build settings.

Comment: Did the same .. Thanks @Toby :)